# Perforce: Keeping Perforce from altering text-file format

Tags: perforce, file-format

Is there a way to tell Perforce to leave text files alone without setting the file-type as binary?  Or barring that, is there a way to tell the Perforce client to diff binaries?  Binary usually isn't desirable, because I lose the ability to diff.

To clarify: If I edit and make changes to a *.txt file on my window client, newlines will have CR+LF as per the DOS format.  But if I P4 sync on a Unix client, it will have LF only. I need Perforce to keep the format as-is, regardless of where the Perforce client lives.

That said, I do have a work-around:  Set file-type as binary; and/or create a branch with text files set as "text", and integrate periodically back into the mainline where text files are set as "binary".  But this is an overly-complicated work-around for what should be a very simple problem.

Finally, I'm on **Perforce** Windows client 2006.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's an IMHO more important use case for the same question: how to store a `build.sh` *and* a `build.bat` in the same directory without breaking either? With network filesystems/VMs/WSL these could even be actively used at the same time. Version control systems should treat user input as "sacred by default".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set all of your client/workspace specs to 'unix' line-endings. Then no conversion will take place when you check in on Windows.

See http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/CR-LF-Issues-and-Text-Line-endings/

Comment: Ok. This is much better.  While not ideal, it's far better than having to create a separate branch.  Thanks!

Comment: Link updated to: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/CR-LF-Issues-and-Text-Line-endings/

Comment: I tried to summarize the (confusing) documentation, please help review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721294/setting-perforce-line-endings/53491975

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! _Note:_ After I selected unix line ending option in Perforce options, I did a "Get Revision" and selected force to re-get the files, and they still were **not** how I wanted them. However, I converted them once again so that they all had their correct line endings, then I submitted to Perforce 1 more time, and now it is finally working correctly.

Answer (score 5):

The Perforce client can handle line ending properly when syncing to different platforms provided you have `LineEnd` option set properly on your client.  Perhaps you have yours set wrong?  Open up your client specs and set the `LineEnd` option according to your needs.

Check out [this KB article](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/CR-LF-Issues-and-Text-Line-endings) on their website for more info.  Here's an excerpt:

> On the server side, Perforce processes
>   all text files using Unix-style LF
>   line-endings. Although Perforce stores
>   server archive files on disk in the
>   operating system's native line
>   termination convention (CR/LF on
>   Windows, LF on Unix), all line-endings
>   are normalized to Unix-style LF
>   line-endings for internal Perforce
>   Server operations such as p4 sync, p4
>   submit  and p4 diff.
>
> On the client workspace side, Perforce
>   handling of line-endings is determined
>   by a global option for each
>   clientspec. When you sync text files
>   to a client workspace with p4 sync, or
>   submit them back to a Perforce Server
>   with p4 submit, their line-endings are
>   converted as specified in the
>   clientspec LineEnd section.

Comment: I was afraid of that, but thank you for the article.  Simply put, our Unix perforce clients (and file server) must be able to hold a mix of Windows and Unix text files.

Even worse:  We have certain localization text files (akin to Java properties files) which the Perforce server mangles.  Alas, the only solution there is to set things to binary.

Comment: @hythlodayr: Do you currently have a support contract with Perforce?  If so, you could give them a call.  Perhaps they know some tricks that can get it to behave the way you want.

Comment: The trouble is that it doesn't work and Perforce refuse to acknowledge the bug.
Perforce corrupts all text files by default if you ever submit a file from *nix that has Windows line endings or vice-versa.

Comment: _... all line-endings are normalized to Unix-style LF..._ is confusing and contradicted by these two other statements on the same page: _On UNIX and Mac OS X client workspaces, the default local setting does not cause any line-end conversion_, and: _saving a text file with CRLF line-endings in a "unix" workspace and then submitting it results in the files being stored in the depot with extra CR characters at the end of each line...._

Answer (score 3):

When adding text files that you want to be considered binary to Perforce, use the command `p4 add` with the `-t` option to override the type mapping table. See the documentation [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/add.html#1040670). The example given there is `p4 add -t binary file.pdf`.

Answer (score 3):

I have just come across exactly the same problem, but have a better solution that does not involve changing client specs (which are international, and not all of which I have write access to).

All of our clients are Windows PCs, but Cygwin is included within the Perforce Depot. Cygwin is a Windows implementation of Unix, and requires that text files use LF for line endings.

A possible solution for older versions of Cygwin is to mount the root using the "text" option, meaning that files can have CR+LF line endings. However, on upgrading to Cygwin 1.7.9, this no longer worked, as mounts are transient unless they are written into /etc/fstab. I did not manage to make this work.

Luckily, the Perforce Guru sitting next to me came up with the solution of changing the filetype to **binary+D**, which uses the same RCS incremental patch storage as text files, but without the automatic line ending conversion.

I can diff these "text" files successfully between my local workspace and the depot.

Answer (score -5):

Give the files a different extension.

Comment: Nope, as these are supposed to be production-quality files.  One should be able to sync and copy into the environment seamlessly and hassle-free.  In the same vein, unix2dos isn't an option either.