# How can I configure bash to handle CRLF shell scripts?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, line-endings

I want to execute bash scripts that happen to use Windows/CRLF line endings.

I know of the tofrodos package, and how to `fromdos` files, but if possible, I'd like to run them without any modification.

Is there an environment variable that will force bash to handle CRLF?

Comment: No, there is not such an environmental variable.

Comment: I almost left a bogus answer - with bash on cygwin you can do `set -o igncr`, and there was talk of extending that to bash on Linux, but it never happened apparently.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps like this?

```
dos2unix < script.sh|bash -s
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments this is the better option, since it allows the script to read from stdin by running dos2unix and not bash in a subshell:

```
bash <(dos2unix < script.sh)
```

Comment: This will fail if the script requires any kind of input. In those cases, you can use `bash <(dos2unix yourscript)`

Comment: I think you mean `bash <(dos2unix < yourscript)`. Otherwise it will convert the file and write nothing to stdout. But, yes, that's a better option.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a transparent workaround for you:

```
cat > $'/bin/bash\r' << "EOF"
#!/bin/bash
script=$1
shift
exec bash <(tr -d '\r' < "$script") "$@"
EOF
```

This gets rid of the problem once and for all by allowing you to execute all your system's Windows CRLF scripts as if they used UNIX eol (with `./yourscript`), rather than having to specify it for each particular invocation. (beware though: `bash yourscript` or `source yourscript` will still fail).

It works because DOS style files, from a UNIX point of view, specify the interpretter as "/bin/bash^M". We override that file to strip the carriage returns from the script and run actual bash on the result.

You can do the same for different interpretters like `/bin/sh` if you want.

Comment: They do different things. dos2unix modifies scripts, while this allows you to run them unmodified (as per original question).

Comment: And why would you want to modify the script each time you run it instead of modifying it once and be done? Is CPU time for free?

Comment: Without argument `dos2unix` reads from stdin and writes to stdout (is a filter) so it doesn't necessarily modify the file.

Comment: You either have to modify the file or modify the command used to run it. This approach doesn't require you to modify anything.

Comment: No. Again, `dos2unix` doesn't require you to modify anything (unlike `fromdos`).

Comment: Ok, then explain how I can run my unmodified `script.sh`  with my unmodified command `./script.sh`

Comment: @m0skit0 You would have to modify every time you check out from Git, and that gets annoying.

Comment: @StevePitchers You're a programmer. Automate it.

Comment: This solution does not work for sourcing crlf formatted files

Comment: re: `why modify the script each time, instead of just once` because 99% of the time, the CRLF is just fine; 90% of the time I am in cygwin with a bash that understands CRLF, 9% of the time I am in a real Windows CMD window and needs the CRLF, and only 1% of the time am I in a real LINUX bash that doesn't understand CRLF.