# Perforce Line Endings per file

Tags: cygwin, perforce

My Perforce-based project supports both Linux and Cygwin platforms with the same shell scripts (e.g. `build_project.sh`). But Perforce defaults line endings for text files to the local platform ([Docs](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3096)).  This causes `\r\n` newlines in the `.sh` scripts, which fail on Cygwin.

Some of the ideas I've thought of so far:

1. *Is there a way to make Cygwin accept \r\n files?* (Without having to run `dos2unix`, the files fetch as read-only).
2. *Is there a way to set specific files to be text, but with Unix line endings for everyone?* (I am guessing, "no", but thought I'd check.)
3. Of course I can set the entire workspace's line endings to `\n` (unix). But this makes the Windows clients unhappy with their `.bat` files being `\n` instead of `\r\n`.  Also if the setting is per workspace (I can't recall), then a workspace setup is slightly harder for the new Windows user as they must set that option.
4. Set the `.sh` files to be "binary", but then we lose the text diffs on those files.  *Is there a workaround for this?  Is this the common (good) hack?*

This is a fairly minor nit, but I suspect that some of you have a BKM for this pattern.

Thanks.

EDIT: Craig's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13636059/799829) seems to suggest that using Unix line endings will just leave files with `\r\n`'s alone if they are originally submitted that way.

EDIT: To force bash (i.e. Cygwin) to accept files with `\r\n` endings, one can specify `set -o igncr` in the script.  This is nice if one expects Cygwin users to that might not be very Unix literate (my case) or when we can't globally impose the trigger in the solution below for some other reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that when you install Cygwin you can configure it to use Windows line endings.  Leaving that aside, though:

If you use the "unix" LineEnd for absolutely everyone, then all of your text files will have their own internally-consistent line endings (but will not be necessarily consistent with the client platforms).  This works by virtue of the fact that the Windows files will end up having the \r as part of the content of the line, so when being synced out in "unix" format they'll have \r\n endings.

The thing to watch out for is mixing and matching LineEnd settings when doing this -- if somebody with a "win" or "local" LineEnd syncs that same file, now they have \r\r\n endings!  So if you want to go with the per-file line ending plan, make sure EVERYONE uses "unix" as their LineEnd.  This is pretty easy to do with a trigger, e.g.:

```
Triggers:
    form-in client "sed -i %quote%s/LineEnd:.*/LineEnd: unix/%quote% %formfile%"
```